# Showing two types of currencies in Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, e-commerce

I´m building a rails e commerce app, I had all prices in Dollars but now my client want's to show the prices also in Euros.

And the client wants to be able to have different prices for each currency, so I can´t link the dollar amount to the rate of Euro against Dollar to display the prices.

In other words the client must be able to have two inputs to enter prices, one for dollars and one for Euros which are then displayed on the product page.

The only way that I figure to do this is to add another column to the database and call it `price_euros` or something like that.

Because my lack of experience I wanted to ask here if there is another easier way to do this?

Thanks in advance
D

this is the `show.html.erb`in views/products

```
<div class="row product_top">

    <div class="container">

    <% breadcrumb :products %>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 center-block">


     <div class="product_description">

        <h3><%= @product.name %></h3>
        <h4><%#=@product.material %></h4>
        <p><%= @product.description %></p>
        <p class="price"> Designer: </p>
        <p><%= @product.designer.designer_name %></p>

        <p>In stock: <%= @product.stock_quantity %> </p>
     </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
         <p> Price: <%= number_to_currency @product.price, class: 'price' %></p>
        </div>
        <div class="row add_to_cart">   
            <p><%= link_to 'Add to cart', add_cart_path, method: :post %></p>
        </div>


    </div>


   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 center-block" >

  <%= image_tag @product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive"  %>



  </div>
    <p>
  <% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>
   <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(@product) %> |
  <% end %>
   <%= link_to 'Back',  root_path %>
  </p>


  </div>  

</div>
```

This is the `_form.html.erb`partial were the admin enter prices

```
<%= form_for @product, multipart: true do |f| %>
  <% if @product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<div class="container">
      <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :name %><br>
          <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", rows: "5" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :designer %><br>
          <%= f.select :designer_id, Designer.all.map { |c| [ c.designer_name, c.id ] } %>

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :description %><br>
          <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control", rows: "5"  %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <%= f.label :price %><br>
         <%= f.text_field :price %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <%= f.label :image %><br>
         <%= f.file_field :image %>
      </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         <%= f.label :stock_quantity %><br>
          <%= f.number_field :stock_quantity %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :category %><br>
          <%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.map { |c| [ c.name, c.id ] } %>
       </div>
        <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit %>
        </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This is my Product model `product.rb`

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base


    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader



    validates_presence_of :name, :price, :stock_quantity
    validates_numericality_of :price, :stock_quantity

    belongs_to :designer
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :page

    def self.search(query)

     where("name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%") 
    end


end
```

this is the product_controller.rb

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :initialize_cart
  before_action :authenticate_admin!, only: [ :new, :edit, :update, :create, :destroy ]
  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def search

    @products = Product.search(params[:query]).order("created_at DESC")
    @categories = Category.joins(:products).where(:products => {:id => @products.map{|x| x.id }}).distinct

  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit

  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :price, :image, :category_id, :stock_quantity, :designer_id, :query)
    end
end
```

Comment: Adding another column is the way to go. To avoid confusion, you should probably rename the former `price` column, too. Something like `price_usd` and `price_eur`. Remember not to use floats to store currency.

Comment: What's the argument against having a method that simply converts the price? The trouble with storing each separately is that as the value of the dollar and/or euro fluctuate one or both of the prices will change as well. If the dollar is the default price, then a `as_euro` method that converts the dollar price into euros will get the trick done. Of course, you might be fine with prices going out of sync.

Comment: Yeah I know, the client wants to be able to enter amounts not in sync of the exchange rate. Maybe a product costs $100, but 600 in euros... thats what the client wants, thats what the client gets :)